# How to implement smart panel mode like Marvel Unlimited comics application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I need to implement "Guided View" functionality like DC Comics or Marvel comics applications.
I don't have an idea to start this functionality. any one can please suggest me on this.
Below is the link for Guided view details [Guided View link.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GoodUXInTheWildAComicBookGeekReturnsAfterTwentyYearsAwayToABraveNewDigitalWorld.aspx)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what does this `smart panel mode viewer` look like? Mind to add some screenshot?

Comment: Please check the updated question and give me solution.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Even with the screen shots.

Comment: Please check the updated video.

Comment: Question is too broad and should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

If the server provides you the x, y coordinates and height, width of each frame than you can zoom that part(frame) of the whole image. You know the initial position of your frame and final position of your frame where it should be, now move the frame from its initial position to final position.

There are two animations happening here.

1. moving the correct frame in the centre and
2. moving the outer solid black part which covers/hides everything surrounding the frame.

First, forget about the fluid effect and concentrate on just bringing the frame to the centre.

Second, concentrate on bringing the frame to the centre along with black part covering the frame's surrounding without any fluid effect.

Third, you know the initial and final position of frame and black part. Animate them.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am able to calculate the zoom value but I am unable to calculate the x, y positions where we have to start the zoom in given the image. Please find the following code of IOS. I am implemented as is in IOS, but it's not working in Android. Please some body help.                                                                                                                       CGFloat heightOffset = (((frameRect.size.height * zoomScale)
- (self.pageScrollView.bounds.size.height)) / 2);
CGFloat widthOffset = (((frameRect.size.width * zoomScale) -
(self.pageScrollView.bounds.size.width)) / 2);

Comment: First of all you need to use CPD file for JSON. It will provide the panel information (i.e frame origin x origin y, height width etc) which you can use to calculate the targeted frame. Use the aspect ratio for image and then calculate the frame using percentage value given in CPD json. Example. if your image is of 320 * 568 and in CPD it is showing for panel 1 (x: 10, y : 10) then you actual origin x will be 32 and actual origin y will be 56.8. Using the same check panel's height and width and transform accordingly. First focus on panel zoom and center then focus on black layer.